# GPG automatic encrypt/sign the clipboard through bash

Tags: bash, gnupg

I have the following script that allows me to output the content of my clipboard. I want to tweak it so I can sign/encrypt the content of the clipboard.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! tty -s && stdin=$(</dev/stdin) && [[ "$stdin" ]]; then
   stdin=$stdin$'\n'$(cat)
   qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper setClipboardContents "$stdin"
exit
fi
   qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper getClipboardContents
```

With **gpg -sa** allows me to do something like a echo "blah" | gpg -sa will allow me to sign the string.

A **bonus** would be to send the signed content back into the clipboard.

Comment: can you do
````qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper setClipboardContents `echo `qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper getClipboardContents` | gpg -sa ` ````?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but I merely use this incantation from the command line.

> pbpaste| gpg --clearsign | pbcopy

If gpg-agent is running, this will prompt me for the passphrase, unless it's cached.